# Why is it showing red for test coverage

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

This function is used to query the database to search for a specific category. The testcase which i wrote for this function covers the entire code by when I see the code coverage using eclipse ecelma it shows red for a specific line. Can someone help me to rectify this?

```
@Override
public List<Services> searchCategory(String name) throws CategoryNameNotFoundException{

    logger.info("{}.{}",new ServicesBoImpl().getClass().getPackageName(), new ServicesBoImpl().getClass().getName());
    logger.info("Function: searchCategory(), Information: querying the database for the search categories");
    List<Services> searchCategory = jdbcTemplate.query(env.getProperty("searchCategory"), new PreparedStatementSetter() {

        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
            ps.setString(1, name+"%");

        }
    } ,new SearchCategoryRowMapper());

    if(searchCategory.size()==0) {
        logger.info("Function: searchCategory(), Information: Throwing CategoryNameNotFoundException because the paticular category is not found");
        throw new CategoryNameNotFoundException("Category Not Found");
    }
    return searchCategory;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What logic are you trying to cover by writing this UT ? No logic is executed inside test...

Assuming that `serviceBoImpl` is mock:

```
@Test(expected = CategoryNameNotFoundException.class)
public void testIfSearchCategoryThrowsException() {
    Mockito.doThrow(CategoryNameNotFoundException).when(serviceBoImpl).searchCategory("a!@")
    ...here execution which calls this method...
}
```

Remember that this test will not cover logic of `searchCategory` method as it is throwing an error once it is executed